# Disable other checkboxes if two of them are selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I am having below 4 checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="41" name="4[]" value="abc" style="width:10px"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="42" name="4[]" value="qwe" style="width:10px"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="43" name="4[]" value="xyz" style="width:10px"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="44" name="4[]" value="pqr" style="width:10px"></td>
```

I need a way to disabled other checkboxes if I select two of them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: id should be unique..!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ESH54/

Comment: this may help you [disable checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853081/disabling-checkboxes-after-specified-amount-are-selected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(":checkbox[name='4[]']").change(function(){
  if ($(":checkbox[name='4[]']:checked").length == 2)                                              
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);  
  else                                                     
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false); 
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R7Cwg/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= 2) {
       this.checked = false;
       console.log(this.value)
   }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/89/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

> Javascript

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled',true);
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
}
else{
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled','');
}
});
```

> HTML

```
1 <input type="checkbox" name="finallevelusers[]" value="1"/>
2 <input type="checkbox" name="finallevelusers[]" value="1"/>
3 <input type="checkbox" name="finallevelusers[]" value="1"/>
4 <input type="checkbox" name="finallevelusers[]" value="1"/>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/gSSLG/339/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ANc3/2/)**

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    if(this.checked && $(':checked').length == 2){
        $('[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

- Use unique Id attributes for your elements.
- If there is no common attribute, use a common class name of a generic selector like `$('[type="checkbox"]')`
- `$(':checked').length` with `:checked` pseudo lets you find only checked inputs.
- `.prop('disabled',true);` is used to disable the inputs - Refer **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all start to add unique id to each checkbox.
Then you can attach function to change event such like that:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
...
});
```

then simply count :checked items and voila:

```
var n = $("input:checked").length;
```

rest you can do on your own i suppose.