# Checking for any two checked checkboxes inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a buildTree(); function that builds checkboxes in LIs within nested ULs. The outermost UL is wrapped inside div#tree.

**HTML**

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="speed parent-list">
            <input type="checkbox" name="speed" id="speed">speed<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
            <ul class="speed" style="display: block;">
            <li class="hor_speed"><input type="checkbox" name="hor_speed" id="hor_speed">hor_speed</li>
            <li class="ver_speed"><input type="checkbox" name="ver_speed" id="ver_speed">ver_speed</li>
            <li class="heading"><input type="checkbox" name="heading" id="heading">heading</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="health"><input type="checkbox" name="heading" id="heading">health</li>
        <li class="battery_level"><input type="checkbox" name="heading" id="heading">battery_level</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want all other checkboxes to be disabled once any two checkboxes inside the tree are checked.  I have done this much so far but it does not work.

**JS**

```
buildTree();

var checkboxes = $('#tree [type=checkbox]');

checkboxes.change(function(){
  if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length === 2){
   checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else {
   checkboxes.prop('disabled',false);
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**
The code works perfect if I place the rendered tree in the HTML file directly but once it it rendered using jquery, it does not work.

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question earlier today? That looks like one of the answers.

Comment: Seems to work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGVxT/)

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't you. Do you know Raj? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240621/disable-other-checkboxes-if-two-of-them-are-selected-using-jquery#24240710

Comment: @Barmar: he did not asked it. that was somebody else.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240621/disable-other-checkboxes-if-two-of-them-are-selected-using-jquery/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I have updated the question. I think that will help

Comment: @ReccurNishan: have you seen the link to the question for which this question is marked as duplicate?? it eaxactly does the same stuff.

Comment: @ReccurNishan, May my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239210/jquery-event-not-triggering-for-dom-elements-created-after-page-load help. Also it would be nice if you add code of `buildTree();`

Comment: @Barmar I don't know Raj

Comment: @ReccurNishan: why did not you mentioned that before in the question??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are loading the content dynamically, you need event delegation to attach the event to dynamically added DOM. Something like this:

```
 $('#tree').on('change','[type=checkbox]',function(){
 if($('#tree [type=checkbox]').filter(':checked').length === 2){
   $('#tree [type=checkbox]').filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled',true);
 }
 else {
   $('#tree [type=checkbox]').prop('disabled',false);
 }});
```